# Basement Wall with Stucco/Concrete that needs to be removed

Tags: concrete, basement, foundation, waterproofing, stucco

Just bought a 1960 house with unfinished portion of a basement that has had previous water intrusion and the crack has been injected. There are a few lingering cracks I want to deal with. Wall has weird stucco/popcorn type of concrete coating, swirled on about 1/16 inch thick. I want to put liquid rubber primer and a sealant on this entire wall. Can I just primer it then seal it with a liquid rubber product as it is or should I get to bare concrete? Thanks!

Comment: how well is it bonded to the wall?

Comment: Step one would be the **sample to an asbestos lab** before generating dust, for "popcorn texture" in a **1960** house. Suspect until proven otherwise.

Comment: And no, we won't be able to tell if the texture material contains asbestos by looking at a picture of it - it will need to be tested.

Comment: @ecnerwal have you ever seen popcorn texture on walls? I have not it is way two soft. We could probably tell with a good clear photo on this one.

Answer (score 0):

That is a skim coat and depending on how well it was applied it can be difficult to remove. I use a needle scaler (welders use these to relieve stress and quickly clean slag from rust) I got my first one from harbor freight years ago and literarily war it out doing similar work. It is not hard but time consuming. I don’t know if there is an electric version but it was recommended by a friend that is a millwright.
[needle scaler](https://www.harborfreight.com/air-needle-scaler-1108.html). I googled needle scaler and there are quite a few on line the last one I purchased from HF has probable been used over 100 hours, the one before that lasted 10+ years they really make the job easy. I have no connection to HF except having purchased a few of there tools some are real junk but I have a few that have been recommended by friends that have lasted well beyond my expectations.

Comment: "All surfaces must be free of grease, oil, wax, salt, dirt, and other contaminants." – [rustoleum.com](https://www.rustoleum.com/pages/industrialsolutions/resources/surface-preparation/surface-preparation-guide/) - if it doesn't come off with a scaler, it isn't a 'contaminant'. - I can just about quote that by heart, but I still read every label. "RTFM"